# Testing React components that import images works in one project but I am facing issues in another project

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Project A :

- "react": "^18.2.0",
- "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
- "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",

Project B:

- "react": "^17.0.2",
- "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.3",
- "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",

In Project A, I have tested components that import images (svg) without any issues but in Project B, jest is throwing an error where the image is being imported. I googled around and found that it is because jest cannot recognize other file formats.

What I can't understand is why did this issue come in one project and not another? Is it somehow related to the versions of the dependencies?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.